# Repetir uma função N vezes

Tags: javascript, funções

Preciso repetir uma função 200 vezes mas não estou a conseguir obter o resultado que pretendo.

A função que pretendo que seja repetida é `function duplicate`:

```
original = document.getElementById('clone');
lista = document.getElementById('lista');
document.getElementById('more').onclick = duplicate;
i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

  function duplicate() {
    clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  
    i = i + 1;
  
    clone.id = "clone" + i;
   
    span = clone.getElementsByClassName("cloneRef")[0];  //mudar cloneRef
  
    span.innerText = ""+i;
  
    lista.appendChild(clone);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que possa executar a função repetidas vezes, você deve cria-la 1 vez e depois apenas chama-la e isso não está acontecendo no seu código.

```
for(i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  function duplicate() {
```

Ao fazer isso, toda vez que o for roda, ele tenta criar uma nova função com o nome 'duplicate', o que irá retornar um erro. Para corrigir isso, é necessário apenas criar a função fora do `for` e depois chamar ela dentro dele

```
original = document.getElementById('clone');
lista = document.getElementById('lista');
document.getElementById('more').onclick = duplicate;


function duplicate() {
    clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    i = i + 1;
    clone.id = "clone" + i;
    span = clone.getElementsByClassName("cloneRef")[0];  //mudar cloneRef
    span.innerText = ""+i;
    console.log(i);
    lista.appendChild(clone);
  }

for(i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    duplicate();
}
```

E com isso a função `js` já estará funcionando

Comment: Na verdade não dá erro, ele simplesmente cria a função várias vezes. E a cada vez que cria uma, ela sobrescreve a função anterior: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33973987

Comment: Nem no console? Geralmente quando executo a parte do js, verifico bastante o console e normalmente apresenta muitas mensagens de erro por lá @hkotsubo

Comment: Acabei de testar no console do Chrome e no Node, ambos funcionaram: https://ideone.com/PGKiOV

Comment: Provavelmente foi erro de como eu estava fazendo então... mas achei isso estranho, simbora pesquisar